# React multiple occurrences replace using regular expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I've been trying to replace patterned occurrences from copy pasted 24 page string from PDF, to create array of collected substrings in react.js .
The format is as follows:

```
    var result = /(?<= startpoint)(.*)(?=endpoint)/g;
```

Due to the fact that symbols are included in the string, I am trying to delete '/' symbols from above result.

```
    var symbremoved = result.replace(/[/]/, "");
```

Yet I get an error saying result.replace is not a function.

Is there a rule that patterned Regular Expressions I have to follow?

Comment: You're calling the `replace` method on a `result` variable which is not a string but a `RegExp`. The `replace` method can be called only on a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned as I'm doing, but the problem is that your `result` is not a string, and replace is a string method.

You have to use `myString.replaceAll(/myRegex/g, "")`, the `g` is important, as you can see in the print bellow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did not recognize regexp was for strings only, the easy fix was to fix the whole string before splitting the substring. Solutions in coding can be confusingly simple sometimes.